# MongoDB upgrade version of dbpath

Tags: mongodb

I have the database files, /data/db/ (these are from the version 3.6.3 MongoDB)
But I looked the documentation of MongoDB up and I saw and it isn't possible anymore to install the MongoDB 3.6.3.

So how am I able to update the old database files to use them with the version MongoDB 4.4

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You must do it one by one:

[Upgrade a Standalone to 4.0](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/release-notes/4.0-upgrade-standalone/)

> The following steps outline the procedure to upgrade a standalone mongod from version 3.6 to 4.0.

[Upgrade a Standalone to 4.2](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/release-notes/4.2-upgrade-standalone/)

> he following steps outline the procedure to upgrade a standalone mongod from version 4.0 to 4.2

[Upgrade a Standalone to 4.4](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/release-notes/4.4-upgrade-standalone/)

> The following steps outline the procedure to upgrade a standalone mongod from version 4.2 to 4.4.

Comment: I actually meant that my files, which I backed up as a backup of the database has version 3.6.3, my MongoDB itself has version 4.4.0

Comment: See [Archived Releases](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community/releases/archive)